# Would my DSL for Lua work...? (this seems too simply to be true)

Tags: lua, preprocessor, dsl, luajit

I really love **[Lua](http://lua.org)** as a programming language BUT, it bugs me unbelievably to have to constantly type "`local`" for all my local variables.

It just makes my code look more cluttered.

So I am wondering, can I create a Domain Specific Language (DSL) on top of Lua to simply have the following variable naming convention.

1. If a variable name is in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS, then it's a global variable
2. Else, the variable is a `local` variable

**Question**: Would this work - Yes or no?

In other words:

```
-- In Lua 5.2
isGlobalinLua  = "is global in default Lua"
GLOBALVAR      = "is global var in default Lua"
local localvar = "is local var in default Lua"

-- In my DSL Lua language
isLocalinDSLLua = "is local in DSL Lua"  -- translates to: local isLocalinDSLLua = ...
GLOBALVAR       = "is global DSL Lua"
localvar        = "is local var in DSL Lua"  -- translates to: local localvar = ...
```

So now, the following code in default Lua:

```
myglobal = 10
local a = 1
if a > 1 then
    local b = 2
    print b
else
    local c = 3
    print c + myglobal
end
```

With my DSL Lua:

```
MYGLOBAL = 10
a = 1
if a > 1 then
    b = 2
    print b
else
    c = 3
    print c + MYGLOBAL
end
```

**UPDATE**:

What about local functions?

How would the following code work?

```
myfunc = function (...)   -- local myfunc = function (...)
```

I'm not certain I'd want to make every global function in all caps.

Maybe I just ignore functions and require the '`local`' identifier ... thoughts?

Comment: Interesting question. +1 I am interested in seeing if this is correct or what the correct way of doing this would be.

Comment: Of course you "can" do this; write a preprocessor that reads your DSL and outputs Lua source. This is not a trivial task, nor is it obvious to me how worthwhile it would be. I personally see little point in DSLs that work at the same level of abstraction as the implementation language; they do not save time nor prevent errors. The "domain" in a "domain-specific" language usually refers to the end-user domain; such a game player, accountant, businessman, et al.

Comment: So, after a year, what came out of this idea?

Comment: @lhf, I didn't create this but it's given me inspiration.  http://moonscript.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moonscript](http://moonscript.org/) already has all variables local by default and you only need to use export keyword to declare a global. It's a very nice next-generation, coffeescript-like language and it compiles to Lua. I use it wherever I used to use Lua.

```
foo = 'bar' -- local
square (x) -> x*x -- local

-- globals
export square
export MY_GLOBAL = 12

export class Foo
    new: (bar) => @bar = bar -- self.bar = bar
    get_bar: => @bar
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a coffeescript fan. Do you know how I could pull out the portion of Moonscript that I want to use without using the rest?

Answer (score 5):

Since the change you want is relatively simple, you basically have two options. You can try out [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/):

> Metalua is a language and a compiler which provide ...
>
> - A complete macro system, similar in power to what's offfered by Lisp dialects or Template Haskell; manipulated programs can be seen as
>     source code, as abstract syntax trees, or as an arbitrary mix thereof,
>     whichever suits your task better.
> - A dynamically extensible parser, which lets you support your macros with a syntax that blends nicely with the rest of the language.

Or you can use [token filters](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#tokenf):

> The token filter works by giving you the opportunity to inspect and
>   alter the stream of tokens coming from the lexer before they go to the
>   parser. You get to see only tokens and you are only allowed to generate
>   tokens -- you're not allowed to see the text coming to the lexer nor to
>   generate text to go into the lexer.

Both approaches have their pros and cons. Metalua allows you to do high-level language modifications in Lua, but has a steeper learning curve. Token filters allow you to do simple modifications to the token stream, but have a limited power (see the [2005 talk](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/oral/luaws05.pdf)).

I'm not sure if token filters are enough for your case, because inserting `local` before every lowercase-starting identifier in assignment will only work for simple cases. What about the following code?

```
a = 1
a = a * a
```

Do you want to convert it to a single `local`, or you want two?

```
local a = 1     vs.    local a = 1
a * a                  local a = a * a  -- valid in Lua, creates a new variable
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, but the result is not called a "domain-specific language".  It is called a "preprocessor".

I, too, was once incredibly bugged by a problem with Lua—it lacks a `switch` or `case` statement.  I actually wound up modifying the implementation to support this feature.  But eventually I decided I didn't care to be programming in a dialect that only I used.

If you have C programming skills, the Lua implementation is very clean, and the easiest way for you to achieve your goal is probably just to modify the implementation.